# Magento different config files for live and staging

Tags: php, magento

Is it possible to have different config.xml files for live, staging and dev versions of the site.

Im thinking that there should be a live.xml, local.xml and staging.xml and these should be set up once and then controlled via htaccess environment variable or something

Is this possible?

Answer (score 5):

No, nothing supports this out of the box with Magento, and there's no module I know of that offers this functionality.

You **could** implement a version of this if you wanted to.  All of Magento's config files are (or should be, don't hold me to it) loaded via the `Mage_Core_Model_Config` class.

```
#File: app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Config.php
public function loadModulesConfiguration($fileName, $mergeToObject = null, $mergeModel=null)
{
    $disableLocalModules = !$this->_canUseLocalModules();

    if ($mergeToObject === null) {
        $mergeToObject = clone $this->_prototype;
        $mergeToObject->loadString('<config/>');
    }
    if ($mergeModel === null) {
        $mergeModel = clone $this->_prototype;
    }
    $modules = $this->getNode('modules')->children();
    foreach ($modules as $modName=>$module) {
        if ($module->is('active')) {
            if ($disableLocalModules && ('local' === (string)$module->codePool)) {
                continue;
            }
            $configFile = $this->getModuleDir('etc', $modName).DS.$fileName;
            if ($mergeModel->loadFile($configFile)) {
                $mergeToObject->extend($mergeModel, true);
            }
        }
    }
    return $mergeToObject;
}
```

You could create a class rewrite for this model that would alter the $filename based on environment, and then load the appropriate configuration file.

While it's an interesting idea, I don't think it's a good one.  Differences in environment is something that should be handled on a deployment level, and a module's `config.xml` file shouldn't have any environment specific information in it anyways.  Environment specific information is kept in one location

```
app/etc/local.xml
```

Your build/deploy system should modify local.xml as needed depending on which environment you're deploying to.